# Mercedes - What type of connector is this?

Tags: electrical, mercedes-benz, connector, wire

I need to buy a new connector for the light in the boot of my Mercedes C180 W204. However I have been unable to find out what the name of this connector is and where I can purchase it. Does anyone have any ideas? It’s a simple 2 pin connector (used for connecting the boot light).

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connector will most likely be made by TE Connectivity (TE.com).

Use their site to search for the part number that should be on one side or inside the connector.

If there is no part number use the search function. Choose Parts, Automotive connectors, connector housings, housings for female terminals. Use the filters to narrow down the results such as number of positions, colour, non sealed etc etc.

Failing that Mercedes are pretty good at supplying connectors and pins so speak to the parts department and see if they can get it.

Comment: solder / crimp wires onto the pins and use a cheaper / simpler connection also less time involved...

Comment: Had to contact Mercedes in the end. The connector is made by Delphi.

Answer (score 2):

If all else fails, wrecking yards (I'm not sure what they call them in the UK) may have the same car you own. It's as simple as clipping one out of a wrecked car, then soldering it into yours. It's been my experience, such places don't charge much for it and it'll be an exact fit. If the wreckers don't have your exact model, you may also look at models close to yours, as manufacturers (yes, even MB) use the same connector in the same place in many different models to save engineering/manufacturing costs.